# R ggplot2: unify fill for grouped samples with binary data in geom_tile

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to display an "absence/presence" heatmap with geom_tile in R. I would like to have a fill for "1" or "present" if a feature (here: OTU) can be found in at least one of the samples within a group. So below is the example code, where I grouped the samples by site:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  OTU = c("OTU001", "OTU002", "OTU003", "OTU004", "OTU005"),
  Sample1 = c(0,0,1,1,0),
  Sample2 = c(1,0,0,1,0),
  Sample3 = c(1,1,0,1,0),
  Sample4 = c(1,1,1,1,0))   
molten_df <- melt(df)

# add group data
sites <- data.frame(
  site = c(rep("site_A", 10), rep("site_B", 10)))
molten_df2 <- cbind(molten_df, sites)

# plot heatmap based on group variable sites
ggplot(molten_df2, aes(x = site, y = OTU, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile()
```

[image]

the tile (site_A, OTU003) consists of the values Sample1 = 1 and Sample2 = 0 and the outcome is 0. On the other hand, the tile (site_B, OTU003) also has Sample3 = 0 and Sample4 = 1, but it turns out as 1. Maybe it uses the last value for the fill? As I would like to display 1 if an OTU appears in any of the grouped samples regardless of the order, I wondered if anyone knows how to do this within ggplot2?

The other way I thought of (but failed coding) is to write a function that sets the remaining values of a given tile to 1, if at least one 1 appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With library `dplyr`, you can create a new variable indicating if OTU at a given site is present in, at least, one sample :

```
tmp = group_by(molten_df2,OTU, site) %>% 
  summarise(., PA=as.factor(ifelse(sum(value)>0,1,0)))
```

Then plot :

```
ggplot(tmp, aes(x = site, y = OTU, fill = PA)) +
  geom_tile()
```

[image]

Or directly inside the ggplot function :

```
ggplot(group_by(molten_df2,OTU, site) %>%
         summarise(., PA=factor(ifelse(sum(value)>0,1,0))), 
       aes(x = site, y = OTU, fill =PA)) +
  geom_tile()
```

Comment: thank you, that worked well. Do you have any idea how the described behavior was caused in the geom_tile() call?

Comment: Your welcome ! For each tile, all values are plotted but they are superposed (the first, the second... until the last one). So you can only see the color associated to the last value.

Comment: perfect, now it makes sense!